# How does python know that you need to interface the requests module through api.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-module

In my foray into learning more about Python, I've been studying the structure of a Python module called `requests` or sometimes known as `python-requests`.

Now, the question is [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py), which is a link to the `api.py` file in the `requests` github repo, you will see that it provides the interfacing for the module, which is to be expected. My question is how does Python know that all the interfacing is done in `api.py`, and this, is it mandetory to include an `api.py` file when making a reusable module?

I would be grateful for any links to documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: [`https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py)

E.g. if 'requests' is a directory, which has `__init__.py`, Python executes this file each time it sees `from requests import ...` or `import requests`.

See more in [Modues](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).